# Add INJECT_PERMISSION to app

Tags: android

How to sign my application so I can install it as an system application?

I generate apk. And then i type these commands in terminal:

```
adb remount
adb push app-debug.apk /system/app/
adb shell chmod 644 /system/app/app-debug.apk
adb reboot
```

Ofc, i have root on my phone. Is LG G2.

After finish rebooting phone the app is exist and i can't uninstall it so i think that is from now system app. But..

```
/**
 * Match signature of application to identify that if it is signed by system
 * or not.
 *
 * @param packageName
 *            package of application. Can not be blank.
 * @return <code>true</code> if application is signed by system certificate,
 *         otherwise <code>false</code>
 */
public boolean isSystemApp(String packageName) {
    try {
        // Get packageinfo for target application
        PackageInfo targetPkgInfo = mPackageManager.getPackageInfo(
                packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        // Get packageinfo for system package
        PackageInfo sys = mPackageManager.getPackageInfo(
                SYSTEM_PACKAGE_NAME, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        // Match both packageinfo for there signatures
        return (targetPkgInfo != null && targetPkgInfo.signatures != null && sys.signatures[0]
                .equals(targetPkgInfo.signatures[0]));
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Above function return false when i run it with my app package.
And also i still getting error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission
```

Ofc, i have added INJECT_EVENTS permission in android manifest. I need it to simulate touch and simulate key press from my service to other apps.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INJECT_EVENTS permission is a signature level permission. Thus, your app would have to be signed with the same key as the system image. Otherwise, as in your case, this permission is not granted.